# SQL Cannot Group on InnerJoin - Duplicates appearing

Tags: sql-server, join

**UPDATED SP TO INCLUDE CHANGES BELOW:**

I have the following SQL database schema / relationships

[image]

This is a booking system with 30 minute timeslots and based on a locationid, memberid and the date i needed to get all of the timeslots when a location is open for a specific date.  I have a query (which a friend helped me with) which took into consideration if the Gym was opened or closed however I have recently added an OffPeakHours table to be able to dictate the hours that are peak / offpeak.  The problem is that for each Day of the week (numeric): (Mon - Sun = 1-7) there are multiple off peak hour slots:

e.g. Monday-friday: 8:30am to 11:30am and 2pm to 5:30pm

[image]

When i have done the additional join for the Off Peak hours i am now getting duplicate rows when i should be (obviously) getting distinct rows.  Can someone please have a look at the SP below and let me know what you think.

```
    USE [TestDB]
        GO
        /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetUpcomingBookingSlots]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 9:37:56 PM ******/
        SET ANSI_NULLS ON
        GO
        SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO

        ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetUpcomingBookingSlots] 


            @LocationId int, 
            @CurrentDateTime datetime,
            @MemberID int
        AS
        BEGIN


        declare @DayOne Date

        declare @WindowTimeStart time

        set datefirst 1
        select @DayOne = CONVERT(date, @CurrentDateTime)
        select @WindowTimeStart = CONVERT(time,@CurrentDateTime)


        -- Day One

        select
            @DayOne BookingDay,
            datename(dw,DATEPART(dw, @DayOne)-1) DayOfWeek,
            ts.StartTime,
            ts.EndTime,
            ts.id TimeSlotId,
            l.Id as LocationId,
            (select count(id) from SessionBooking where LocationId = @LocationId and TimeSlotId = ts.Id and [Date] = @DayOne) as BookingCount,
            l.AvailableSlots,
            case   
                when
                    ts.StartTime between oho.AltOpenTime and oho.AltCloseTme and 
                    ts.EndTime between oho.AltOpenTime and oho.AltCloseTme THEN 'Closed' /* This doesn't seem right to me */
                when
                    sb.TimeSlotId is not null THEN 'Booked'
                else 'Available'
            end as [Status],
            case   
                when
                    ts.StartTime between opo.StartTime and opo.EndTime and 
                    ts.EndTime between opo.StartTime and opo.EndTime THEN 'Off Peak'
                else 'Peak'
            end as BookingStatus,
            case
                when
                    ts.StartTime between oho.AltOpenTime and oho.AltCloseTme and 
                    ts.EndTime between oho.AltOpenTime and oho.AltCloseTme THEN oho.OverrideReason
                else ''
            end as ClosureReason

        from
        location as l
        inner join OpeningHour as oh
            on oh.LocationId = l.Id and oh.DateOfWeek = datepart(dw, @DayOne)
        inner join OffPeakHours as opo
            on opo.LocationId = l.Id and opo.DateOfWeek = datepart(dw, @DayOne)
        left outer join OpeningHourOverride as oho
            on oho.LocationId = l.Id and @DayOne between oho.OverrideStartDate and oho.OverrideEndDate
        inner join timeslot as ts
            on ts.StartTime >= oh.OpenTime and ts.EndTime < oh.CloseTime
        left outer join
        (
            select * from SessionBooking 
            where SessionBooking.Date = @DayOne and SessionBooking.MemberId = @MemberID
        ) as sb
            on sb.TimeSlotID = ts.id
        where
            ts.StartTime > @WindowTimeStart /* why didn't you just make this a time variable? */
        order by 
            BookingDay, ts.StartTime


        END
```

Thanks.

UPDATE: SQL DDL

```
        USE [RitualDB]
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[AspNetUsers]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetUsers](
        [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
        [Email] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
        [EmailConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [PasswordHash] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [SecurityStamp] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [PhoneNumberConfirmed] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [TwoFactorEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [LockoutEndDateUtc] [datetime] NULL,
        [LockoutEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,
        [AccessFailedCount] [int] NOT NULL,
        [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
        [Salutation] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [LastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Pin] [int] NOT NULL,
        [HomePhone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [MobilePhone] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [Birthday] [date] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.AspNetUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Location]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [Address] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [PhoneNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [PostCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [Country] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [TimeZoneOffset] [smallint] NOT NULL,
        [Currency] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
        [AvailableSlots] [smallint] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Location_AvailableSlots]  DEFAULT ((0)),
        [Longitude] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL,
        [Latitude] [decimal](9, 6) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Location] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Member]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Member](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [IdentificationNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
        [EmailOptOut] [bit] NULL,
        [HomeLocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [AspNetUserId] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Member] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OffPeakHours]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OffPeakHours](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [DateOfWeek] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [EndTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [LocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_OffPeakHours] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OpeningHour]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OpeningHour](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [DateOfWeek] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [OpenTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [CloseTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [LocationId] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_OpeningHour] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[OpeningHourOverride]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[OpeningHourOverride](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [OverrideStartDate] [date] NOT NULL,
        [OverrideEndDate] [date] NOT NULL,
        [DayOfWeek] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [AltOpenTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [AltCloseTme] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [OverrideReason] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [LocationId] [int] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_OpeningHourOverride] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SessionBooking]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [MemberId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [LocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
        [BookingStateId] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RPEFeeling] [int] NOT NULL,
        [RPEPush] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Notes] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [TimeSlotId] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_Booking] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[SessionBookingState]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SessionBookingState](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_BookingState] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TimeSlot]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeSlot](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [EndTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_TimeSlot] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TrialTimeBlock]    Script Date: 2/27/2015 10:32:40 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TrialTimeBlock](
        [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [DateOfWeek] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
        [StartTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [EndTime] [time](7) NOT NULL,
        [LocationId] [int] NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_TrialTimeBlock] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Member]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Member_AspNetUsers] FOREIGN KEY([AspNetUserId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Member] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Member_AspNetUsers]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Member]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Member_Location] FOREIGN KEY([HomeLocationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Member] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Member_Location]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OffPeakHours]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OffPeakHours_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OffPeakHours] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OffPeakHours_Location]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OpeningHour]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OpeningHour_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OpeningHour] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OpeningHour_Location]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OpeningHourOverride]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_OpeningHourOverride_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[OpeningHourOverride] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_OpeningHourOverride_Location]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_BookingState] FOREIGN KEY([BookingStateId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[SessionBookingState] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_BookingState]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_Location]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_Member] FOREIGN KEY([MemberId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Member] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_Member]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_TimeSlot] FOREIGN KEY([TimeSlotId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[TimeSlot] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[SessionBooking] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Booking_TimeSlot]
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TrialTimeBlock]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TrialTimeBlock_Location] FOREIGN KEY([LocationId])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Location] ([Id])
    GO
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TrialTimeBlock] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TrialTimeBlock_Location]
    GO
```

Example Results (With Duplicates)

[image]

Comment: I'm not saying that this query is wrong, but consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Oh, this really is SQL server

Comment: Indeed it is..What did you think it was going to be?

Comment: Well, it was tagged MySQL

Comment: Apologies for that..wasn't intended..

Answer (score 0):

So just check that your timeslot overlaps the off-peak hours. Add this to your join condition:

```
and ts.StartTime <= opo.EndTime and ts.EndTime >= opo.StartTime
```

Btw, this condition is negating all the left outer join:

```
where ts.StartTime >= oh.OpenTime and ts.EndTime < oh.CloseTime
```

You should use `set` rather than `select` for variable assignment.

I took a stab at re-writing the query in a way it made sense to me:

```
select
    @DayOne as BookingDay,
    datename(dw, datepart(dw, @DayOne)-1) as DayOfWeek,
    ts.StartTime,
    ts.EndTime,
    ts.id as TimeSlotId,
    l.LocationId,
    (select count(id) from SessionBooking where LocationId = @LocationId and TimeSlotId = ts.Id and [Date] = @DayOne) as BookingCount,
    l.AvailableSlots,
    case   
        when
            ts.StartTime between oho.AltOpenTime and oho.AltCloseTme and 
            ts.EndTime between oho.AltOpenTime and oho.AltCloseTme THEN 'Closed' /* This doesn't seem right to me */
        when
            sb.TimeSlotId is not null THEN 'Booked'
        else 'Available'
    end as [Status],
    case   
        when
            ts.StartTime between opo.StartTime and opo.EndTime and 
            ts.EndTime between opo.StartTime and opo.EndTime THEN 'Off Peak'
        else 'Peak'
    end as BookingStatus,
    case
        when
            ts.StartTime between oho.AltOpenTime and oho.AltCloseTme and 
            ts.EndTime between oho.AltOpenTime and oho.AltCloseTme THEN oho.OverrideReason
        else ''
    end as ClosureReason

from
location as l
inner join OpeningHour as oh
    on oh.LocationId = l.LocationId and oh.DateOfWeek = datepart(dw, @DayOne)
inner join timeslot as ts
    on ts.StartTime >= oh.OpenTime and ts.EndTime < oh.CloseTime
inner join OffPeakHours as opo
    on  opo.LocationId = l.LocationId and opo.DateOfWeek = datepart(dw, @DayOne)
        and ts.StartTime <= opo.EndTime and ts.EndTime >= opo.StartTime
left outer join OpeningHourOverride as oho
    on oho.LocationId = l.LocationId and @DayOne between oho.OverrideStartDate and oho.OverrideEndDate
left outer join
(
    select * from SessionBooking
    where sb.Date = @DayOne and sb.MemberId = @MemberID
) as sb
    on sb.TimeSlotID = ts.id
where
    ts.StartTime > @WindowTimeStart /* why didn't you just make this a time variable? */
order by 
    BookingDay, StartTime
```

Comment: I have used your Stored Procedure and added the columns i require back in.  The problem that i am still having is that my off-peak hours have multiple instances per day (i.e. a morning and evening session)  there may be "n" number of off peak hours per day.  The reason i am getting duplicate values is because of the number of offpeak blocks in each day is 2 (for saturday which only has one it works great!)

I basically need to be able to do a GROUP BY on the off peak hours but i cannot get the syntax correct for it to allow me to do this.

Comment: I rewrote the query as you had it and without the extra join condition I suggested at the top of my answer. I understand the problem as you describe it and `group by` does not seem to be what you need. Limiting the join to a single row is what you're really trying to do.

Comment: So this will work even for multiple off peak hour sections for a specific day?  I'm guessing I could use the same principle for opening hours if there was multiple opening hour configs for a day also (ie open in morning and evening)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something has your example been included for this change. How do I limit the join to a single row?

Comment: I just edited the answer to add the condition in the join. You didn't post all your data and I'm just making guesses about how it looks. I also wrote `<=` and `>=` rather than strict inequalities and I'm not entirely sure that's right either.

Comment: The line
        and ts.StartTime <= opo.EndTime and ts.EndTime >= opo.StartTime /* added here */
comes back with the error:

Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetUpcomingBookingSlots, Line 66
The multi-part identifier "ts.StartTime" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure GetUpcomingBookingSlots, Line 66
The multi-part identifier "ts.EndTime" could not be bound.

Comment: I moved up the join to timeslots.

Answer (score 0):

This is getting very close now...for clarity i will use this section to show the current output..

[image]

As you can see from these results i am missing some timeslot results in the middle of the day. It appears to only show me values that are within the off peak hour overrides...Would a sub query be easier? I am not that precious about absolute performance....